# File.Copy() Отображает что знаки некоректны

Tags: c#

Программа закидывает файлы из одной папки в другую .С большей частью файлов программа выплонила что от нее тербовали но на файлах : (gpzu.pdf) (gradostroitelnyy-plan-zemelnogo-uchastka.pdf) (Primer_GPZU.pdf) она решила выдать мне ошибку ,сославшись на некоректные знаки;
Проверив путь я увидел следующиее

[image: gpzu.pdf]
[image: gradostroitelnyy-plan-zemelnogo-uchastka.pdf]
[image: Primer_GPZU.pdf]

как видите некорректных знаков нет.

код следующий:

```
string finaldir = newpath;
finaldir += "\\" + kvartal_number;
finaldir += "\\" + house_number;
finaldir += "\\" + Path.GetFileName(file);

try
{
    File.Copy(file, finaldir, true);
}
catch (ArgumentException)
{
    MessageBox.Show(finaldir);//имя файла введено некорректно
}
```

Заранее спасибо за помощь )

Comment: [Path.GetInvalidPathChars](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.getinvalidpathchars?view=net-7.0), [Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.getinvalidfilenamechars?view=net-7.0)

Comment: Что за конкатенации? Познакомьтесь с `Path.Combine` и уберите запрещенные символи из строк. Покажите точный текст ошибки и строку, в которой она возникает.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> как видите некорректных знаков нет.

Отлично вижу, что некорректные знаки есть. Переводы строк. Ну и пробелы в конце имён папок на винде тоже не допускаются.

Comment: Да проблема оказалась в пробелах добавив. Trim() проблема решилась. Большое спасибо за помощь)